# Declare ambient variable if not null in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following line `declare var Notification: any;`.

It's working fine, for the most part. But on iOS I see the following exception - `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Notification`. iOS doesn't seem to support `Notification`, is there a way to check if is it null, and if it is do not declare it. Something like this -

```
if (Notification)
  declare var Notification: any;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it (compile time)

```
declare var Notification: any;  // <= this is for the compiler only
```

Test it (runtime)

```
if (typeof Notification !== 'undefined') {   
   //non IOS stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ambient declarations such as `declare var`are only useful during compilation time. They are not available during execution time.

The message error you have means that `Notification` are not defined. Using `declare var` will not change that fact. You miss in your code an actual instanciation/definition of your variable `Notification`.